# Try to start a IntentService results "RuntimeException: Failure delivering result to activity"

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I'm trying to use a service(**MainService.class**) to start an intentService(**ConnectToServerIntentService.class**) and result a RuntimeException as mentioned. The error is appear in a method **sendRequestToServer()** at **MainService.class** when submit an intent to **ConnectToServerIntentService.class**.

Code

**MainService.class:**

```
public class MainService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createGoogleApiClient();
    connectGoogleApiClient();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    disconnectGoogleApiClient();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private static GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

private void createGoogleApiClient(){
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

private void connectGoogleApiClient(){
    if(!googleApiClient.isConnected()){
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

private void disconnectGoogleApiClient(){
    if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private final static long LOCATION_INTERVAL=30*60*1000;
private final static long LOCATION_FASTEST_INTERVAL=30*60*1000;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    System.out.println("GoogleApiClient onConnected");
    LocationRequest locationRequest=LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    System.out.println("GoogleApiClient onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    System.out.println("GoogleApiClient onConnectionFailed");
    System.out.println(connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
}

static Location currentLocation;
private final static String URL="http://225.225.225.225/PM25Predictor_beta/Reciever.jsp";

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location!=null){
        currentLocation=location;
    }else{
        currentLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    }

    if(currentLocation!=null){
        sendRequestToServer(currentLocation.getLatitude()+","+currentLocation.getLongitude(),candidateStationLatLng);
    }else{
        sendRequestToServer(null,candidateStationLatLng);
    }
}

private void sendRequestToServer(String currentStationLatLng, String[] candidateStationLatLng){
    String currentStationData="CURRENT_STATION_DATA:"+currentStationLatLng;
    ArrayList<String> requestDataSet_al=new ArrayList<>();
    requestDataSet_al.add(URL);
    requestDataSet_al.add(currentStationData);
    if(candidateStationLatLng!=null){
        String[] candidateStationData=new String[candidateStationLatLng.length];
        for(int i=0; i<candidateStationLatLng.length; i++){
            candidateStationData[i]="CANDIDATE_STATION_DATA:"+candidateStationLatLng[i];
        }
        requestDataSet_al.addAll(Arrays.asList(candidateStationData));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<requestDataSet_al.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(requestDataSet_al.get(i));
    }

    Intent requestIntent=new Intent(this,ConnectToServerIntentService.class);
    Bundle requestBundle=new Bundle();
    requestBundle.putStringArray("CONNECT_TO_SERVER_REQUEST", requestDataSet_al.toArray(new String[requestDataSet_al.size()]));
    requestIntent.putExtras(requestBundle);
    startService(requestIntent);

    long updateTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent timerIntent=new Intent(this,TimerIntentService.class);
    Bundle timerBundle=new Bundle();
    timerBundle.putLong("UPDATE_TIME", updateTime);
    timerIntent.putExtras(timerBundle);
    startService(timerIntent);*//the problem is there.*
}

String[] candidateStationLatLng;
public void submitRequest(String[] checkedCity){
    candidateStationLatLng=new String[checkedCity.length];
    for(int i=0; i<candidateStationLatLng.length; i++){
        candidateStationLatLng[i]=checkedCity[i].split(",")[2]+","+checkedCity[i].split(",")[3];
    }
    onLocationChanged(currentLocation);
}
```

}

**ConnectToServerIntentService.class**

```
public class ConnectToServerIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final String CONNECT_TO_SERVER_INTENT_SERVICE_ACTION="CONNECT_TO_SERVER_INTENT_SERVICE_ACTION";

public ConnectToServerIntentService() {
    super("ConnectToServerIntentService");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("ConnectToServerIntentService on Destroy!");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String connectToServerResponse=connectToServer(intent.getExtras().getStringArray("CONNECT_TO_SERVER_REQUEST"));
    if(connectToServerResponse!=null){
        Intent responseIntent=new Intent(CONNECT_TO_SERVER_INTENT_SERVICE_ACTION);
        Bundle responseBundle=new Bundle();
        responseBundle.putString("CONNECT_TO_SERVER_RESPONSE",connectToServerResponse);
        responseIntent.putExtras(responseBundle);
        sendBroadcast(responseIntent);
    }
}

private String connectToServer(String... params){
    try{
        URL url=new URL(params[0]);

        ArrayList<String> stationLatLng_al=new ArrayList<>();
        stationLatLng_al.addAll(Arrays.asList(params));

        stationLatLng_al.trimToSize();
        String[] stationLatLng=new String[stationLatLng_al.size()];
        stationLatLng_al.toArray(stationLatLng);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(getPostData(stationLatLng).getBytes("utf-8"));

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        int responseCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode==200){
            System.out.println("Connection done.");
            return getStringFromInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Connection fail!");
            return null;
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static String getPostData(String[] stationLatLng){
    String result=null;

    for(int i=0; i<stationLatLng.length; i++){
        if(i==0){
            result=stationLatLng[i].split(":")[0]+"="+stationLatLng[i].split(":")[1];
        }else{
            result=result+"&"+stationLatLng[i].split(":")[0]+"="+stationLatLng[i].split(":")[1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while((len=in.read(buffer))!=-1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    String result=out.toString("utf-8");
    out.close();
    return result;
}
```

}

**the Error message:**

```
02-28 17:16:25.882 9227-9227/com.example.user.pm25predictortest I/System.out: http://225.225.225.225/PM25Predictor_beta/Reciever.jsp
02-28 17:16:25.882 9227-9227/com.example.user.pm25predictortest I/System.out: CURRENT_STATION_DATA:22.6412969,120.5964363
02-28 17:16:25.882 9227-9227/com.example.user.pm25predictortest I/System.out: CANDIDATE_STATION_DATA:24.8238676,120.9474747
02-28 17:16:25.882 9227-9227/com.example.user.pm25predictortest I/System.out: CANDIDATE_STATION_DATA:24.7920604,120.9933678
02-28 17:16:25.882 9227-9227/com.example.user.pm25predictortest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-28 17:16:25.892 9227-9227/com.example.user.pm25predictortest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.user.pm25predictortest, PID: 9227
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.user.pm25predictortest/.MainActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.user.pm25predictortest/com.example.user.pm25predictortest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3558)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3601)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1333)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:921)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:522)
                                                                                      at com.example.user.pm25predictortest.MainService.sendRequestToServer(MainService.java:129)
                                                                                      at com.example.user.pm25predictortest.MainService.onLocationChanged(MainService.java:102)
                                                                                      at com.example.user.pm25predictortest.MainService.submitRequest(MainService.java:145)
                                                                                      at com.example.user.pm25predictortest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:74)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6177)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3554)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1333) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
```

the System.out.println() in the Error message are the contain of requestDataSet_al(MainService.class->sendRequestToServer), so I don't think it's bundle's problem. 
any solution will be appreciate, thank you!

Comment: What if you do `MainActivity.this.startService(requestIntent);` same error or differ ?

Comment: the same error, but thx.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code fully but what I can suggest is to override `onStartCommand` in `ConnectToServerIntentService` class.

As per the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) *It is called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service by calling `startService(Intent)`, providing the arguments it supplied and a unique integer token representing the start request.*

It's recommended to put onCreate logic inside `onStartCommand` method in `IntentService`. It looks something like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   //Add your onCreate Logic here
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: the reason i use IntentService is to put the task into non-UI thread, but if i put my command into onStartCommand() will make the task run in UI thread?

Comment: Haha  It won't affect UI- thread. It is ok that you used startService from background thread. But I am telling you to override onStartCommand inside the IntentService. Have you seen the documentation I provided link.

Comment: what did you add inside onStartCommand. This exception is thrown when Network operations are added in UI-Thread. Use AsyncTask

Comment: [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) runs task in non-ui thread, it's the same as AsyncTask but simpler I think.

Comment: I've solved it, I tried to  call a method submitRequest() by create a new object like this `new MainService().submitRequest()` which will initialize the elements in the new MainService() and which is wrong. Thank you for the try [Shree Krishna](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5067493/shree-krishna).

Comment: @鍾哲豪 You are welcome, that method was in MainService so that it showed so. Changing that only worked or you applied my suggestions too ?

Comment: One problem is if we override onStartCommand method, then onHandleIntent won't be called.